# Create two edit button with different settings

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I've created a version tracking that will show all the edited document inside view. What if I want to make all document be draft at the same time, and during that, document can't be edit. And after I click save, all draft document will be saved at the same time.

**Edit 1**

I have one more question when I do version tracking, how can I make all response document cannot be edit? only current document can be edit?

**UPDATE QUESTION**

1. Currently, I am using version tracking to show all list with all edit document. So for now, every time I click EDIT, it will show all history of updated.
2. So I want create a situation where I have 2 edit option which is **EDIT** and **PC Specification**. I want to set PC Specification after edit document, it updated all history under version tracking, but for EDIT I don't want it update under version tracking. Because, for EDIT function, it only for edit one or two information BUT for PC Specification, it is to update all information. For example, I have 3 documents inside the "Computer" view.
   [image: view]
3. When I open one document, it will show document details. On top menu, I have two buttons which are **Edit** and **Close Windows**. So can I add one more toolbar? Which is **PC Spec** as below?
   [image: pcspec]
4. So I will click the **PC Spec** button on the toolbar then the documents will open as a new document with same document information. Same as edit function. After I click save, it overwrite document + show edit history
5. For another situation where I click **EDIT**, same as **PC Spec** but after I click save, it overwrite document only.
   [image: edit]
6. As shown below, the history is when document edit using **PC Spec** only.
   [image: update]
7. Another question, I have "Archived" view. How can I show only history of document inside "Archived" view?

Hope you guys can understand this. Please ask me anything if you not understand. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question, to make all response documents non-editable, you will have to

- Give your regular users Author access instead of Editor access in the database's Access Control List and assign them a role, which I'll call "AppUsers".
- Give yourself and anyone else who will be responsible for managing the app a role which I'll call "AppAdmins".
- Add a hidden computed field with type "Authors" to the form and set the initial value formula to

  @If(@IsResponseDoc;"[AppAdmins]";"[AppUsers]":"[AppAdmins]")
- Note that this will not have any effect on existing documents until you refresh and re-save them.

Then, you're going to have to hope that automatic versioning refreshes the documents. I'm not sure if it does or does not. If it does not, then you're probably going to have to give up on using the native versioning and write your own version using LotusScript. As I recall, that's what was done in the standard Lotus document library template, because the native versioning is pretty limited in what it can do.

As for your first question, I'm sorry but I really don't understand what you're asking. I can't tell in some parts whether you are telling us what you have already done, or what you want to do. Here on StackOverflow, the best way to get useful answers is to show us very clearly what you have tried, tell us what happens, and tell us what you thought should have happened instead. This is a place for helping you fix your code, not a place to get tutorials that amount to explicit instructions on how to write your code in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new with Notes. I will try your suggestion. Can I ask, which one should I check the hide options for your suggestion? I will update my question later.

Comment: Hi, I have another question. Where can I assign the role for user and me which is AppUsers and AppAdmins as you mention?

Comment: You should put the hidden field on its own line at the top or the bottom of the form, and you should Roles are assigned in the database ACL. You need to go through some tutorials about basic Notes development, or buy one of the books that cover it. Stackoverflow is not the place to get step-by-step instruction.  Here's a link to a site that offers a free introductory tutorial: http://www.tlcc.com/freeddcourse.

Comment: And Bob Balaban's old book about Domino and Java is posted for free, here. It's even older, and yes, it's oriented toward Java, but it is still one of the best explanations of the basics of Notes architecture that there is. http://bobzblog.com/tuxedoguy.nsf/dx/programming-domino-with-java-final-flush?opendocument

Comment: And here's a book that's a little newer and broader. It's still way out of date, but the basics haven't changed. You're not going to find many (if any) newer books. (Note: I wrote some chapters in this one, but I get no royalties.) https://www.amazon.com/Lotus-Notes-Domino-Programming-Bible/dp/0764526111/